# How do I change my symbology in arcpy to have a clear outline point?

Tags: python, arcgis, arcpy

I am not sure why my arcpy result's point outline is not changing to clear in ArcGIS Pro. Everything else works, except for the outline syntax. Is there anything wrong with my syntax or this may be a ArcPro bug?

```
`#Add spatial join layer to the current map
p = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject('CURRENT')
m = p.listMaps('CompTool')[0]
layer = Stream_Comp.getOutput(0)
m.addDataFromPath(layer)

#Format symbology rendering 
l = m.listLayers(StreamComp_Name)[0]
sym = l.symbology


if sym.renderer.type == 'SimpleRenderer':
    sym.updateRenderer('GraduatedColorsRenderer')
    sym.renderer.classificationField = Comp_Field
    sym.renderer.classificationMethod = 'NaturalBreaks'
    sym.renderer.breakCount = 7


#Updating Symbology Rendering - error:nothing happens to the symbol outline     
for brk in sym.renderer.classBreaks:
    brk.symbol.size = 6
    brk.symbol.outlineColor = {'RGB' : [0, 0, 0, 0]}`
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to set `l.symbology = sym` at the end of your code example in order to update the rendering.

---

I am using ArcGIS Pro 3.1.2 and I was using a `SimpleRenderer` for the first example:

```
import arcpy

project = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("current")
map = project.listMaps("Buildings")[0]  # map 'Buildings'
layer = map.listLayers("Buildings")[0]  # layer 'Buildings'

symbology = layer.symbology

symbology.updateRenderer("SimpleRenderer")

symbol = symbology.renderer.symbol
symbol.color = {"RGB": [220, 220, 220, 100]}
symbol.outlineColor = {"RGB": [255, 0, 0, 50]}
symbol.size = 5

layer.symbology = symbology  # "re-set" property symbology
```

---

Here is an example using a `GraduatedColorsRenderer`:

```
import arcpy

project = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("current")
map = project.listMaps("Buildings")[0]  # map 'Buildings'
layer = map.listLayers("Buildings")[0]  # layer 'Buildings'

symbology = layer.symbology

symbology.updateRenderer("GraduatedColorsRenderer")

renderer = symbology.renderer
renderer.classificationField = "Shape_Area"
renderer.breakCount = 6
renderer.classificationMethod = "Quantile"
renderer.colorRamp = project.listColorRamps("Green-Blue (Continuous)")[0]

for class_break in renderer.classBreaks:
    class_break.symbol.size = 2
    class_break.symbol.outlineColor = {"RGB" : [0, 0, 0, 100]}
    
layer.symbology = symbology  # "re-set" property symbology
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you put it there by mistake, but you have a " ' " at the end of your `brk.symbol.outlineColor` line. Not sure if it's in your code or not, but if that single quote is there, you're probably getting a mismatched quotes syntax error.